# Bind items from multiple list in a grid

Tags: spgridview

I want to bind the items from multiple list into a gridview. I earlier used `SPSiteDataQuery` to bind the items from multiple list in a gridview but then I was not able to cast the items into `ListItemCollection` as I need to get the item property though which I can add a hyperlink field in it with the help of which we can redirect the user to the default edit form of that item.

So how do I bind the items from multiple list into a single grid in a way through which I can get items so that I can navigate to their edit form in the list in which they are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void BindGrid()
    {
        using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
        {
            using (SPWeb objWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
            {
                try
                {
                    SPList List = objWeb.Lists["List1"];
                    SPList List1 = objWeb.Lists["List2"];
                    SPList List2 = objWeb.Lists["List3"];
                    SPList List3 = objWeb.Lists["List4"];
                    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();

                    string where = "<Where><And><Eq>";
                    where += "<FieldRef Name='Status'/>";
                    where += "<Value Type='Choice'>Approved</Value>";
                    where += "</Eq><Eq>";
                    where += "<FieldRef Name='Author' LookupId='True'/>";
                    where += "<Value Type='Text'>" + SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.ID + "</Value>";
                    where += "</Eq></And></Where>";
                    query.Query = where;

                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                    //Add columns to Data Table
                    dt.Columns.Add("Title", typeof(string));
                    dt.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));
                    dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(Int32));
                    dt.Columns.Add("List URL", typeof(string));

                    SPListItemCollection Coll1 = List.GetItems(query);
                    SPListItemCollection Coll2 = List1.GetItems(query);
                    SPListItemCollection Coll3 = List2.GetItems(query);
                    SPListItemCollection Coll4 = List3.GetItems(query);

                    foreach (SPListItem item in Coll1)
                    {
                        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                        row["Title"] = item.Title;
                        row["ID"] = item.ID;
                        row["Status"] = item["Status"];
                        row["List URL"] = SPContext.Current.Web.Url + List.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/EditForm.aspx?ID=" + item.ID + "&Source=/_Layouts/15/hks/getlistitems.aspx";
                        dt.Rows.Add(row);
                    }

                    foreach (SPListItem item in Coll2)
                    {
                        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                        row["Title"] = item.Title;
                        row["ID"] = item.ID;
                        row["Status"] = item["Status"];
                        row["List URL"] = SPContext.Current.Web.Url + List1.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/EditForm.aspx?ID=" + item.ID + "&Source=/_Layouts/15/hks/getlistitems.aspx";
                        dt.Rows.Add(row);
                    }

                    foreach (SPListItem item in Coll3)
                    {
                        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                        row["Title"] = item.Title;
                        row["ID"] = item.ID;
                        row["Status"] = item["Status"];
                        row["List URL"] = SPContext.Current.Web.Url + List2.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/EditForm.aspx?ID=" + item.ID + "&Source=/_Layouts/15/hks/getlistitems.aspx";
                        dt.Rows.Add(row);
                    }

                    foreach (SPListItem item in Coll4)
                    {
                        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                        row["Title"] = item.Title;
                        row["ID"] = item.ID;
                        row["Status"] = item["Status"];
                        row["List URL"] = SPContext.Current.Web.Url + List3.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/EditForm.aspx?ID=" + item.ID + "&Source=/_Layouts/15/hks/getlistitems.aspx";
                        dt.Rows.Add(row);
                    }
                    //Add Columns to Grid
                    BoundField col1 = new BoundField();
                    col1.HeaderText = "Title";
                    col1.DataField = "Title";
                    mygrid.Columns.Add(col1);

                    BoundField col2 = new BoundField();
                    col2.HeaderText = "ID";
                    col2.DataField = "ID";
                    mygrid.Columns.Add(col2);

                    BoundField col3 = new BoundField();
                    col3.HeaderText = "Status";
                    col3.DataField = "Status";
                    mygrid.Columns.Add(col3);

                    HyperLinkField col4 = new HyperLinkField();
                    col4.HeaderText = "Edit";
                    col4.Text = "Edit Item";
                    col4.DataNavigateUrlFields = new string[] { dt.Columns["List URL"].ToString() };
                    mygrid.Columns.Add(col4);

                    //Bind Data in GridView
                    mygrid.DataSource = dt;
                    mygrid.DataBind();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(SPAlert),
                        "alert", "<script language=\"javascript\">alert('" + ex.Message + " .')</script>");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```